# Monitor USB for camera connection

Tags: c#, windows, camera, usb

I have a USB microscope camera and I would like to open the Windows 10 camera app automatically if the camera gets connected to a USB port. After checking that this isn't possible with Windows 10 at the settings level, I have decided to write a short C# program that monitors the USB ports for a camera device connection (and runs the camera display app).

As to the monitoring I haven't got a slightest clue where to begin. Needless to say that the monitoring program should be lean with respect to blocking ressources, because it would be running all the time. Can I simply obtain an event notification of USB connection? Do I have to expect problems with permissions?

And of course, suggestions for alternative approaches are welcome, if any. Note that I do not want to capture and display video from the camera myself, unless it is easier to do it that way instead of opening the existing camera app.

Comment: Have you considered simply polling for connected cameras?

Comment: Yes, of course :-) I just don't know how to do it. I suppose it will be possible somehow with P/Invoke, but I thought there must be something more simple.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the microscope is using the web-camera interface I would look for guides about how to enumerate and connect to web-cameras. I have found a few alternatives:

1. [Media capture API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera-profiles)
2. [Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/directshow_video.html)
3. [Versatile WebCam](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library)

I had most success with versatile webcam, but if you just want to enumerate devices any of them should do. Aforge is probably the easiest to use.

You can then use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers) to check for devices, and do something if the microscope is connected.

If the microscope is not a webcamera you will need to refer to the camera documentation on how to enumerate devices.

Comment: Being guided by your link to the Media Capture API, I have found out about the UWP example projects, especially the "CameraStarterKit" project. Since this is already a camera app, I think I will manage to poll the USB ports by modifying the code a little. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples